# Array not reading all values

Tags: arrays, bash, directory

I'm trying to get this arrays to work, but it reads only the first folder.

```
SFA=(folder1 folder2)
```

and the code:

```
for folders in "${SFA[@]}"
do
echo /media/$SFA
done
```

But it only seems to iterate trough one folder (tv1) 2 times. I can't see anything wrong with the code...

Comment: That code is correct. You'll have to provide some evidence, or your actual code

Comment: If you're going to reference a folder by name (`tv1`), please use it in your example instead of the made up names `folder1` and `folder2`.

Comment: Also, you want `/media/$folders`, not `/media/$SFA` (which is equivalent to `/media/${SFA[0]}`. Your iteration is fine, you just aren't using the right variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```sh
declare SFA=(folder1 folder2)    
for folders in "${SFA[@]}"; do echo /media/$folders; done
```

The Output will be as follows:

```sh
:~$
/media/folder1
/media/folder2
```

Comment: Thanx guys, I used the wrong variabe. Too tired I guess. But it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I found my own mistake...
The code looks like this now and works as intended.

```
FOLDERARRAY=(tv1 tv2)

    ### Check for FOLDERS in FOLDERARRAY
    #
    for FOLDERS in "${FOLDERARRAY[@]}"
    do
        #   echo /media/$SFA
        if [ ! -d /media/$FOLDERS ]; then
            echo /media/$FOLDERS; status="Couldn't find /media/$FOLDERS"
            # exit 0
        else 
            echo "found folder: /media/$FOLDERS"
            find /media/${FOLDERARRAY} -mtime -7 -type f -size +2048 -exec 
    basename {} \;| sort |uniq  >> /tmp/v$DATE-weekly.txt;
        fi
```